# Node.js SQLite not returning anything

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am trying to user SQLite in Node.js

```
function sqlget(command, param = 0) {
    var args = param;
    if(param == 0) args = [];
    var retval = null;
    db.all(command, args, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            retval = result;
        }
    });
    return retval;
}
```

When I try this, it returns null. However, If I just use db.get, It works well. The program executes db.all {...}, too.

Comment: Use `result` in `else` block, like `console.log(result)` .

Comment: I think it is because function can't return json. Any way?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is **retval** returns before **db.all(command, args, (err, result) => {});** callback execute.

Try:

```
function sqlget(command, param = 0) {
    let args = param;
    if(param == 0) args = [];
    db.all(command, args, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } 
        return result;
    });
}
```

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function sqlget(command, param = 0) {
    let args = param;
        if(param == 0) args = [];
        return db.all(command, args, (err, result) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } 
            return result;
        });
    }
```

Comment: it's better to use async-await too, in this part!